# "Godness" vs. "goddess"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, doubled-consonants

I've noticed people use (in speech) the word *godness* for "feminine god", e.g.:

> Oh my **godness**!

However, in classic texts it is *goddess*, e.g. Shakespeare's "King Lear":

> Hear, nature, hear; dear **goddess**, hear!
>   Suspend thy purpose, if thou didst intend
>   To make this creature fruitful!
>   Into her womb convey sterility!

It is my understanding that *godness* can be an urban slang for "divinity", but not for an impersonated deity.

Is *godness* just a mistake?

Comment: Where have you "noticed" this? Can you cite a few references? (This is the first I can recall seeing...)

Comment: Are you sure it's not a typo, that someone meant to write "Oh my **goodness**!" I have *never* seen the usage you show. Could you proved some links to examples?

Comment: Related and posted as comment because it is not a reliable source: 
http://godness.urbanup.com/2385095 
 
"A term popularized by the song Venus, written by the Shocking Blue. Mariska Veres, the lead singer of the band spoke little English upon the recording of the song, and because of this she pronounced "goddess" as "godness."
 
A godness on a mountain top 
Was burning like a silver flame, 
The summit of beauty and love, 
And Venus was her name. 

-Venus, by The Shocking Blue"

Comment: @MετάEd: Definitely not a "reliable source". I always liked Venus by Shocking Blue (not "the", *please!*), and I'm quite sure it starts with [A **goddess** on a mountain top](http://www.oldielyrics.com/lyrics/shocking_blue/venus.html)

Comment: Anyway, even if there are a handful of people who use "godness" the way OP claims when it's **not** either ignorance or a typo, I still think this is Too Localised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I never heard the song before, but in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2DBcbZc3ck) it certainly sounds like *god**n**ess* to me.

Comment: @TimLymington it was just an exclamation in a verbal speech (updated Q)

Comment: @StoneyB: Weird. I don't detect that "n" on [this later performance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTb1LYaFV8I&feature=related) (which is not so clear anyway), and Google gives 0 hits for [mariska veres venus lyrics **+godness**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mariska+veres+venus+lyrics+%2Bgodness&oq=mariska+veres+venus+lyrics+%2Bgodness&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Perhaps it was a one-off.

Comment: ...belay that. I just listened to the original '69 recording. No question she sings "godness". On account of not speaking English very well, apparently. Ah well - at least Bananarama ***are*** English, so [they get it right](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JH3WvI_S6-k)

Comment: @FumbleFingers no doubt somebody corrected her after the original recording (the video I linked to is probably synched)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. *Godness* is an established (if rather rare) English word, an obsolete ME synonym of *godhead* reinvented in the 19th century to express ‘divine element or nature’ (*OED 1*). Google finds this employed in a lot of religious and New-Age spiritual contexts.
2. *Godness* is also a surprisingly frequent typo for *goodness* and, occasionally, *goddess*, which you may see most readily by [Google-booking](https://www.google.com/search?q=godness&rlz=1C1GGGE_enUS488US489&oq=godness&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=godness&hl=en&rlz=1C1GGGE_enUS488US489&prmdo=1&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1700,cd_max:1799&tbm=bks&prmd=imvnsfd&ei=NcOJUJr0C4q3yQG8v4Fg&start=40&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=4aadf6606ec02e63&bpcl=35466521&biw=2133&bih=1185) the word for the 18th century and following the hits.
3. [*Urban Dictionary*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=godness) claims that *godness* is a ‘A term popularized by the song Venus, written by the Shocking Blue. Mariska Veres, the lead singer of the band spoke little English upon the recording of the song, and because of this she pronounced “goddess” as “godness.”’

   > A godness on a mountain top
   >   Was burning like a silver flame,
   >   The summit of beauty and love,
   >   And Venus was her name.
   >   -Venus, by The Shocking Blue

UD, alas, does not tell us what the term *means*. It's not in other respects the most reliable source, either, but it cannot be dismissed: this account is echoed [elsewhere](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=1402).

So ‘Oh, my godness’ in *print* is probably (but not certainly) a typo; but if you've actually *heard* it its meaning may be just what you suggested, *divinity*. **EDIT:** Or it may have simply been a slip of the tongue.

[This](http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/godness.html) page from Linguee provides several examples; you may decide for yourself (read: *guess*) which are typos and which legitimate uses.

Comment: Given the relative obscurity of _Godness_ in modern English, I second the notion that it was either misspoken or misheard. In the use identified by @StoneyB I am more familiar with _Godhood_ as well as the mentioned _Godhead_.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing/hearing the word "goodness." You have most likely heard the common exclamation: "Oh my goodness!" If you saw the word in writing than the writer was probably just accidentally omitted the second "o." The reason why I believe this is because the word "godness" is almost if not entirely obsolete.

Comment: Sorry, no. As I said, it was in verbal speech. `ɑ` versus `uː` are too different to mix them.

Comment: I most certainly have never heard an exclamation of "Oh my goodness!" before but it is very common to hear "Oh my goodness!" Which is why I still think that is what you may have heard.

Comment: @cbbcbail, as I understand your comment, it is very common to hear "Oh my goodness!" but you have never heard it as an exclamation.  What, then, have you heard it as?

Comment: @jwpat7 Oh dear, it appears to have auto-corrected to goodness. I am not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean it is incongruous first to say “I most certainly have never heard an exclamation of "Oh my goodness!" before” and then to say  “it is very common to hear "Oh my goodness!"”.

Comment: @jwpat7 Yes, as I said, the first statement is meant to be godness and not goodness but it seems that my computer auto-corrected it to goodness. My comment was meant to read:  
I most certainly have never heard an exclamation of "Oh my **godness**!" before but it is very common to hear "Oh my goodness!" Which is why I still think that is what you may have heard.

Comment: I'm not bytebuster and don't know what bb heard; but at 19 seconds into [Venus by Shocking Blue](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2DBcbZc3ck) (the link in StoneyB Oct 25 '12 at 22:59 comment) it's clearly "The godness on the mountain top".  That aside, I now understand clearly what you meant for your comment to say.